# Identifying software and version range in a sentence

Tags: nlp

I have sentences similar to the following format

> This vulnerability happened in `Firefox` `1.x` before `1.8`, `Safari`
>   `2.x` before `2.8`.

Given the above sentence, I want to extract a dictionary

```
{Firefox: 1.0-1.8, Safari: 2.0-2.8}
```

Problem is how should I identify the version range with the software they belong to, using NLP techniques?

Answer (score 1):

If all your sentences are in the following format(atleast that what I assume), you can parse it with regex instead.

```
`([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)(?:\s+before\s+)(\d+\.\d+)`
```

Using this pattern with the given sentence finds all the software and the versions in it. `re.findall(pattern, sentence)` will give you a list of tuples like this
`[('Firefox', '2.4', '2.5'), ('Safari', '6.0', '6.8')]`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not, need to parse based on meaning. First to identify the range of version, second to identify the object it refers to (probably using named entity recognition), but thanks a lot for the solution!